# Run schtask locally using jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task to run a bat file locally to schedule a task to open a website i used jenkins to automate it i used start cmd.exe /c SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN "myftp" /TR %TN%  /SC daily /ST 14:48:00  it is creating with local cmd but not jenkins windows 
batch shell